# How can you sync multiple outlook calendars including delegated calendars

Tags: exchange, 5.1-lollipop, outlook

So I need to sync a user's calendar to their Galaxy S6's Calendar/Planner they are on the latest OS (Lollipop 5.1), I can't seem to find a way that will allow me to sync their outlook calendar and their boss's calendar to which they have full delegate access.

Is anyone aware of any solution to this? This is in a corporate environment so if the solution is long-winded or very complicated it won't be viable as the user's setup their emails on their phones.

The user can see their calendar fine it's just the delegated calendar that I can't seem to find/sync.

I've tried downloading the Outlook App, multiple calendar apps etc.

Comment: If you go to the Calendar app and go to the menu you should see 'Calendars to Display'. Does the delegated calendar appear there?

Comment: sorry which calendar app are you referring too? (just so I don't spend ages in the wrong place lol)

Comment: I've just checked the [Google Calendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.calendar) app and the extra calendars I have configured (admittedly they're not for exchange) appear in the left slide-out panel. I expect the S6 calendar app (and most other decent calendar apps) will have something similar.

Comment: Yeah it works fine with gmail etc I'm testing on my personal Galaxy S5 (not ideal but should be close enough) and it pulls through everything if I use gmail or the native email client but still not the delegate calender :(. Thanks though :)